# Kibana Aggregate 24 hours

Tags: kibana

I've imported a log file into kibana, with the following fields

```
time,hour
2021-12-10 10:33:37,10
2021-11-17 14:01:46,14
```

I've used a date histogram, and generated the following graph:
[image: date histogram]

However, the log files need to be shifted to a different timezone, is there a way doing this in Kibana, without needing to reupload a log file?